# i need perfect xlsx as well as xls reader script in php

Tags: php, xlsx

I am using [PHPExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader) to read uploaded xls file. But I am not able to read xlsx files saved in excel-2007 format. can someone help me on how to read xlsx file in PHP.

i have also tried [PHPEXCEL](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) , here is main code

```
$fileName = 'test.xlsx';
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error loading file: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n");
}
```

but it gives fatal error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\xls_reader\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\File.php on line 53
```

**Note:** i m using Vertrigo server which have `PHP Version 5.2.6`

Please somebody tell me how to read xls as well as xlsx file with any suitable example or link.
Thank you very very much

Comment: I changed the server from vertrigo to XAMPP..now let me see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EXCEL 2007 document you need the ZipArchive extension which is obviosly not available at your system. If you enable/install this extension you will be fine.

Have a look at [this link](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=233977)

@diEcho: I don't develop on a windows machine so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. What I do remember from my Windows experience, i used to use XAMPP for it instead and that worked for me.

Comment: @Stegeman i have download `php5.2-win32-latest.zip` but don't know how to install in my server. i tried to run `go-pear.bat` file but it ask a lot of questions. can u provide me any link where it is described how to install php extension?

Comment: @diEcho, why don't you just download the version with MSI installer?

Comment: @Alvaro, pardon, i didn't get you. download what? PHP version or ZIP extension? where do i find that? i'll b very thankful if u provide me the link

Comment: @Stegeman, you are right, i also use Xampp always, but here i have to use vertrigo, that is not a good server AFAIK, bcoz it use version 5.2.x wheras PHP officially suggest to use version 5.3.x

Comment: @diEcho, I've figured out your real issue and I've added an answer.

Comment: @diEcho: BTW, I normally download PHP from http://php.net , I thought you were talking about that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the actual question is how to enable the Zip extension under PHP/5.2 in a PHP setup installed from a zipped release. First you have find the `php.ini` file. You can learn its location by running this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Open the file with your favourte text editor and find this line:

```
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Remove the leading semicollon:

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

Restart Apache and you're done.

In PHP/5.3 the extension is already built-in.

Comment: there is  line having `extension=php_zip.dll` in my `php.ini`..:(

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the original answer, which I've already fixed. Make sure the line is uncommented.

Comment: i checked that already but there is only `extension=php_bz2.dll` is uncommented  no `php_zip.dll`

Comment: Well... I'm sorry but I know nothing about VertrigoServ and their web site does not have documentation.